# How to Rename Multiple Columns on a Reset Index with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rename, multiple-columns

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to rename Pandas columns when you try to reset the index.  I see in the documentation that you can use the "name" parameter to set the column name of a reset index if there is only one column, but I'm curious if there is a way to do this for multiple columns.

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'A' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
'B' : ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
'D1' : [1,0,0,0],
'D2' : [0,1,1,0],
'D3' : [0,0,1,1],
})

df1.set_index(['B','A']).stack().reset_index()
```

The result leaves you with:

```
     B   A level_2  0
0   b1  a1      D1  1
1   b1  a1      D2  0
2   b1  a1      D3  0
3   b2  a1      D1  0
4   b2  a1      D2  1
```

You could do:

```
df1.set_index(['B','A']).stack().reset_index(name='my_col')
```

In order to set the name of the last column but I'm wondering if there is a way to use the parameter to set the name of the 'level_2' column as well.

The first thing that came to my mind was to try:

```
df1.set_index(['B','A']).stack().reset_index(name=['my_col2','my_col'])
```

However, that did not work so looking for another way around.  I realize I could always just rename the columns in the next line but was hoping there'd be a cleaner way to do it in one line.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you see, `reset_index()` in your code is actually http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html, so you have only one column. 
What you could do is set name of the columns of the index of your series, and then they will remain as a names of the columns of the DataFrame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reset_index` is not smart enough to do this, but we could leverage methods [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to give names to the index and columns/series before resetting the index; once the names are set up properly, *reset_index* will automatically convert these names to the column names in the result:

Here `rename_axis` gives names to index which is somewhat equivalent to `df.index.names = ...` except in a functional style; `rename` gives name to the Series object:

```
df1.set_index(['B','A']).stack().rename_axis(['B','A','col2']).rename('col').reset_index()

#    B   A  col2    col
#0  b1  a1    D1    1
#1  b1  a1    D2    0
#2  b1  a1    D3    0
#3  b2  a1    D1    0
#4  b2  a1    D2    1
# ..
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options, I believe but `set_axis()` function will do the job if you have just several columns.

```
df1.set_index(['B','A']).stack().reset_index().set_axis(['my_col2','my_col'], axis=1)
```