# Dataframe: shift expanding mean with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, average

I want to have expanding mean give the result excluding the current item, ie, the items prior average. Here's what i'm looking for:

```
d = { 'home' : ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'], 'away' : ['B', 'A','A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
 'aw' : [1,0,0,0,1,0,np.nan],'hw' : [0,1,0,1,0,1, np.nan]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['home', 'away', 'hw', 'aw'])
df2.index = range(1,len(df2) + 1)
df2['homewin_at_home'] = df2.groupby('home')['hw'].apply(pd.expanding_mean)

print df2
```

Result:

```
  home away  hw  aw  homewin_at_home
1    A    B   0   1         0.000000
2    B    A   1   0         1.000000
3    B    A   0   0         0.500000
4    A    B   1   0         0.500000
5    B    A   0   1         0.333333
6    A    B   1   0         **0.666667**
7    A    B NaN NaN         0.666667
```

The number highlighted should be `0.5` as: 'A' won 1 of 2 games home prior to this entry at index = 6. Instead the result includes this game yielding `0.66`. Actual output should be:

```
  home away  hw  aw  homewin_at_home
1    A    B   0   1              NaN
2    B    A   1   0              NaN
3    B    A   0   0         1.000000
4    A    B   1   0         0.000000
5    B    A   0   1         0.500000
6    A    B   1   0         0.500000
7    A    B NaN NaN         0.666667
```

Things i've tried include adding `.shift(1)` and trying to slice `[:-1]` in the groupby but I can't get it to work. Also thought of introducing a helper column but couldn't work out how to keep the original index.

I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122196/how-to-iteratively-count-in-pandas-dataframe) but I prefer this method to the group-apply-split routine. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Calculates the `expanding_mean` and `shifts` the result.

```
df['homewin_at_home'] = df.groupby('home')['hw'].apply(lambda x: pd.expanding_mean(x).shift())
```

or, for more recent versions of pandas:

```
df['homewin_at_home'] = df.groupby('home')['hw'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())

  home away  hw  aw  homewin_at_home
1    A    B   0   1              NaN
2    B    A   1   0              NaN
3    B    A   0   0         1.000000
4    A    B   1   0         0.000000
5    B    A   0   1         0.500000
6    A    B   1   0         0.500000
7    A    B NaN NaN         0.666667
```

Comment: Dear @Stefan thank you for your answer, this works perfectly! Before I had: `df2['homewin_at_home'] = df2.groupby('home')['hw'].apply(pd.expanding_mean).shift(1)` which didn't shift the calculation. I know the purpose of lambda so I think my error was putting the `shift()` in the wrong place? Am I correct?

Comment: Indeed, by pulling `.shift()` inside `.apply()`, the anonymous function represented by `lambda` shifts the result of `expanding_mean` for each group, as opposed to the result for all groups.

Comment: How would one re-write this to deal with a deprecation warning: FutureWarning: pd.expanding_mean is deprecated for Series and will be removed in a future version, replace with 
 Series.expanding(min_periods=1).mean()

Answer (score 1):

While [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1494637/stefan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541262) will do what you asked for, using `apply` will significantly lengthens the execution time if you have a big dataset.

To avoid this, you can instead use a second `groupby` and join back with the original data:

```py
pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.rename(columns={"hw": "homewin_at_home"})
        .set_index("home", append=True)
        .groupby("home")["homewin_at_home"].shift()
        .groupby("home").expanding().mean()
        .droplevel(-1)
        .droplevel(0),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Output:

```
  home away   hw   aw  homewin_at_home
1    A    B  0.0  1.0              NaN
2    B    A  1.0  0.0              NaN
3    B    A  0.0  0.0         1.000000
4    A    B  1.0  0.0         0.000000
5    B    A  0.0  1.0         0.500000
6    A    B  1.0  0.0         0.500000
7    A    B  NaN  NaN         0.666667
```