# Finding outliers in an excel row

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

As an example say column C has 1000 cells and most are filled with '1' however there are a couple of '2' sprinkled in. I'm trying to be able to find how many '2' there are and print the number.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('TestBook')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for cell in ws['C']:
    print(cell.value)
```

How can I iterate through the column and just pull how many twos there are?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iteratively count in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122196/how-to-iteratively-count-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Iterating over columns is covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As @K.Marker pointed out, you can query the count of a specific value in the rows with

```
[c.value for c in ws['C']].count(2)
```

But what if you don't know the values and/or you'd like to see the distribution of the values of a particular row? You can use a `Counter` which has `dict`-like behaviour.

```
In [446]: from collections import Counter

In [448]: from collections import Counter

In [449]: counter = Counter([c.value for c in ws[3]])

In [451]: counter
Out[451]: Counter({1: 17, 2: 5})

In [452]: for k, v in counter.items():
     ...:     print('{0} occurs {1} time(s)'.format(k, v))
     ...:
1 occurs 17 time(s)
2 occurs 5 time(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('TestBook')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_of_twos = [c.value for c in ws["C"]].count(2)
```

The list comprehension creates a list of cell values throughout column C, and it counts how many 2 is in it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for how many 2's are there?

```
count = 0
#load a row in the list
row = list(worksheet.rows)[wantedRowNumber]

#iterate over it and increase the count
for r in row:
    if r==2:
        count+=1
```

Now, this only works with values of "2" and doesn't find other outliers. To find outliers in general you will have to determine a threshold first. In this example I'll use the average value, although you would need to determine the best test to get the threshold for outliers based on your data. Don't worry, statistics are fun!

```
count = 0
#load a row in the list
row = list(worksheet.rows)[wantedRowNumber]

#calculatethe average
#using numpy
import numpy as np
NPavg = np.mean(list)

#without numpy
#need to cast it to float - otherwise it will round it to int
avg=sum(row)/float(len(row))

#iterate over it and increase the count
for r in row:
    #of course use your own threshold, 
    #determined appropriately, instead of average
    if r>NPavg:
        count+=1
```

Comment: Sorry I'll update the orginal post. I'm trying to iterate through column C in the excel sheet. And the data will always be either 1's or 2's.